# How to use custom template in JHipster blueprint?

Tags: jhipster, blueprint

I am trying to override the a template Entity.java.ejs in my custom blueprint to add some extra functionality.  Unfortunately JHipster uses its default one if generate an entity. I don’t want to overwrite the whole writing. Is there a possibility to override only certain ones and use JHipster default templates for the rest?

Comment: I have the same problem with react generator. I found the source code in node modules and they are ejs files. I customized footer but for entity my changes are not showing.

Answer (score 0):

Helo friend,
in this period I see an application jhipster with a partial custom .ejs defining a default for others components.

The problem is that the overriding is very huge, and cabled only for a specific version 6.9.1 of jhipster.

If this is a good idea to custom a particolar application with a particolar version and with a specific cabling code ok, but is not good if you want a generic custom generator jhipster context, where you can "inject" only custom files, giving overriding of all scope original generator.

I try to search some answers searching on web, and your question is anyway a good clue to define a better solution that I see now.

The problem that I see is that jhipster environment dont have a "handling" approach about .ejs templates, when is very strong and straighweird when you use .jdl file .

An easly customization of templates of any jhipster application created with command "jhipster", ad example.

And searching I see this link https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/1749

an issue of original jhipster generator where someone consider a good idea to use "subgenerator" using yeoman to modulerize this templates and with all benefits.
This is a another clue to understand somethings.

good luck and thanks